# Log multiple JavaScript function data outputs in an html table

Tags: javascript, html, function, html-table, getelementbyid

Well, thanks to a user user on this site, I was able to log some data from a JavaScript function into an html table. Now I have another question to ask. How can I run the function multiple times while the page is loading and log the output from that one function into the same html table? Because my code as of now only runs and logs the output of the function once, and when I refresh the page I lose the numbers which were previously generated. I want to be able to run the function say 10 times and display that on the html table. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            R = 10;
            theta = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
            r1 = Math.random() * R;
            r2 = R + (Math.random() * 100);
            ray = r1 + (Math.random() * (r2 - r1));
            point = [ray*Math.cos(theta), ray*Math.sin(theta)];


            var distance = function(x1, y1, rad, x2, y2) {
                return (Math.sqrt(Math.pow((y2 - y1), 2) + Math.pow((x2 - x1), 2))) - rad;
            };

        </script>

    <div>
            <table border="1">
                <th>X Center</th>
                <th>Y Center</th>
                <th>r1</th>
                <th>r2</th>
                <th>X Random</th>
                <th>Y Random</th>
                <th>Distance</th>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" id="x center"/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="y center"/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="r1"/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="r2"/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="x random"/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="y random"/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="displacement"/></td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        <script>
            document.getElementById("x center").value = 0;
            document.getElementById("y center").value = 0;
            document.getElementById("r1").value = r1;
            document.getElementById("r2").value = r2;
            document.getElementById("x random").value = point[0];
            document.getElementById("y random").value = point[1];
            document.getElementById("displacement").value = distance(0,0,R,point[0], point[1]);
        </script>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you want a table with 10 rows if the function runs 10 times? or just the last value?

Comment: yes, ten rows corresponding to the ten times the function ran

Comment: You are overwriting the same element all the time. You need to append a new `tr` with all the `td`s to the table.

Comment: no, the code runs as I want it to. all of those cells are in the same row because they are all from the same event.

Comment: You are calling the event only once and again you are setting the values of the same fields.

Comment: Ok. I see. I was thinking about making the for loop but I wasn't sure how that would go down. I figured that if I did that I would log the same thing to the table ten times.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you wanted:

```
<html>

    <head></head>

    <body>
        <div>
            <table border="1">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>X Center</th>
                        <th>Y Center</th>
                        <th>r1</th>
                        <th>r2</th>
                        <th>X Random</th>
                        <th>Y Random</th>
                        <th>Distance</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="log"></tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <script>
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                addRow();
            }

            function addRow() {
                var R = 10;
                var theta = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
                var r1 = Math.random() * R;
                var r2 = R + (Math.random() * 100);
                var ray = r1 + (Math.random() * (r2 - r1));
                var point = [ray * Math.cos(theta), ray * Math.sin(theta)];
                var dist = distance(0, 0, R, point[0], point[1]);

                var newRow =
                    "<tr>" +
                    "<td>" + 0 + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + 0 + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + r1 + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + r2 + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + point[0] + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + point[1] + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + dist + "</td>" +
                    "</tr>";
                document.getElementById("log").innerHTML += newRow;
            }

            function distance(x1, y1, rad, x2, y2) {
                return (Math.sqrt(Math.pow((y2 - y1), 2) + Math.pow((x2 - x1), 2))) - rad;
            };
        </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: Thanks a million, Balint. I was thinking I could use a for loop but i just wasn't sure if that would be viable while using html.